# How to change which file an external checker uses

Tags: eclipse, plugins, cppcheck, misra

Following this guide https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-codan/index.html I've been able to make a Cppcheck plugin for Eclipse. (It seems to do the exact same thing as CPPCheclipse.) Now I'd like to do a similar plugin for Cppcheck's MISRA addon. I've got the MISRA addon working when running it in the console of Eclipse, and on the command line, getting output like:

> ```
> [C:/.../cpptest.c:8]: (style) Required {censored rule text} [misra-c2012-3.1]
>
> Rule violations found: 1.
> ```

I'm thinking that since the MISRA addon produces the same kind of output on the commandline as Cppcheck, the plugin shouldn't need too many modifications, *however* the MISRA addon needs to use dump-files instead of the "actual" file to produce this output.

I'm wondering how to get my MISRA addon to use the dumpfile instead of the "actual" file. My guess is that something in the InvocationParameters or InvocationParametersProvider needs to be overridden, but I'm not sure what or how to do it.

The dumpfiles are created with the Cppcheck plugin and are located in the same place as the "actual" files.

Comment: Changed this in the code for the MISRA-addon instead of trying to change the arguments in InvocationParameters.

Did so by simply adding ".dump" to the file argument, heh.